# Sed error "sed: -e expression #1, char [#]: extra characters after command"

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

> sed '/\r$/ {N s/\n//}'
>   sed: -e expression #1, char 10: extra characters after command

I want to understand what is wrong with my command line.
When I can do the some of following in a script but not in a command line.

I have been working through the tutorial at www.grymoire.com. When I got stuck at the section
[Working with Multiple Lines](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-51). These script works fine.

```
#!/bin/sh
sed '
# look for a "#" at the end of the line
/#$/ {
# Found one - now read in the next line
    N
# delete the "#" and the new line character, 
    s/#\n//
}' file
```

In my case I am looking for \r or return ^M.

```
#!/bin/sh
sed '
# look for a "#" at the end of the line
/\r$/ {
# Found one - now read in the next line
    N
# delete the "#" and the new line character, 
    s/\r\n//
}' file
```

The problem is when I try to convert it to a single line shell command it gives me an errors.

> sed '/\r$/ {N s/\n//}'
>   sed: -e expression #1, char 10: extra characters after command
>   sed '/\r$/{N s/\n//}'
>   sed: -e expression #1, char 9: extra characters after command
>   sed '/\r$/{Ns/\n//}'
>   sed: -e expression #1, char 8: extra characters after command

I want to understand what is wrong with my command line. 
When I can do the following in a script but not in a command line.

I have created a sed script to do the work I want.

```
cat test.sed 
#!/bin/sed -f
/\r$/ {
N 
s/\n//
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a semicolon `;` to separate `sed` commands on the same line. Specifically, between the `N` and `s`.  No semicolon is needed when there is a newline which is why your script form works.

change

```
sed '/\r$/ {N s/\n//}'
```

to

```
sed '/\r$/ {N; s/\n//}'
             ^
```